# dataTable.Rowfilter always returning first row

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have 2 datagridviews alongside each other, displaying what should be same data from two sources. I test for differences and want to apply a filter to only show those rows where differences exist. I create a DataView for each. From the code below you will see that one DGV is setup using a binding source (dancesbindingsource) and the other sets the DataView directly as the DataSource.  I test for differences and then set the "view_flag" data column of each and then set the filters - using BindingSource.filter on one and DataView.RowFilter on the other.

This all works fine EXCEPT that in the DataView case the first row of the DataTable shows every time, no matter whether the view_flag is on or off. The BindingSource filter works fine. I cannot fathom why.

There appeared to be a similar problem posted 6 months or so ago relating to dataTable.defaultView.RowFilter, but the solution suggested seems to be what I am actually doing and getting the same phenomena.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
private void CheckDanceDataDifferences()
    {
        // Look at common ids in both databases and all data values
        // Start by creating a couple of useful data views
        DataView DOview = new DataView(dotable, "", "DanceID", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
        DataView DMview = new DataView(dmrecords.DMdanceTable, "", "id", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
        dancesBindingSource.DataSource = DOview;
        DMdgv.DataSource = DMview;
        DataGridViewRowCollection DOrows = dancesDataGridView.Rows;
        DataGridViewRowCollection DMrows = DMdgv.Rows;
        List<int> err_ids = new List<int>();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DOrows) {
            int idmrow = DMview.Find(row.Cells["DanceID"].Value);
            if(idmrow >= 0) {
                bool[] err = CompareDataDifferences(row, DMrows[idmrow]);
                if(err != null) { 
                    err_ids.Add(idmrow);
                }
            }
        }

        if (err_ids.Count == 0) {
            MessageBox.Show("No data differences found");
            return;
        }

        int i, j, irow, nerr = err_ids.Count;
        // Note - all view flags have been initialised to 0
        // Now we set set the flags of those we want to see
        for (i = 0; i < nerr; i++) {
            irow = err_ids[i];
            DOrows[irow].Cells["view_flag"].Value = 1;
            DMrows[irow].Cells["view_flag"].Value = 1;
        }
        dancesBindingSource.Filter = "view_flag=1"
        DMview.RowFilter = "view_flag=1";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a EndEdit Method to end an edit procedure. Please try this code.

```
// Note - all view flags have been initialised to 0
// Now we set set the flags of those we want to see
for (i = 0; i < nerr; i++)
{
    irow = err_ids[i];
    DOrows[irow].Cells["view_flag"].Value = 1;
    DMrows[irow].Cells["view_flag"].Value = 1;
    DMview[irow].EndEdit();
}
dancesBindingSource.EndEdit();
dancesBindingSource.Filter = "view_flag=1";
DMview.RowFilter = "view_flag=1";
```